# cloud composer build logs, where are they?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am trying to install pypi dependencies on cloud composer following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies).

The build failed, and the error message says:

```
name: "operations/14021472-6dbe-42b3-8ec1-ba7ac62be60e"
done: true
sequence_number: 1
error {
  code: 0
  message: "The image build failed: Build failed; check build logs for details\n"
}
```

However, I can't find where the build logs are.  Does anyone know the answer?  Thanks

FYI, this is the list of packages I'm trying to install (as a `requirements.txt` file):

```
alembic==0.8.10
bleach==2.1.2
boto3==1.4.5
botocore==1.5.92
certifi==2016.2.28
click==6.7
croniter==0.3.24
dill==0.2.8.2
docutils==0.14
flask==0.11.1
flask-admin==1.4.1
flask-cache==0.13.1
flask-login==0.2.11
flask-swagger==0.2.13
flask-wtf==0.14.2
future==0.16.0
gitdb2==2.0.4
gitpython==2.1.11
gunicorn==19.9.0
html5lib==1.0.1
itsdangerous==0.24
jinja2==2.8
jmespath==0.9.0
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==3.8.0
mako==1.0.7
markdown==2.6.11
markupsafe==1.0
numpy==1.13.1
pandas==0.23.3
psutil==4.4.2
pygments==2.2.0
pyspark
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-editor==1.0.3
python-nvd3==0.14.2
python-slugify==1.2.5
pytz==2018.5
pyyaml==3.12
requests==2.13.0
s3transfer==0.1.10
setproctitle==1.1.10
six==1.11.0
smmap2==2.0.4
sqlalchemy==1.2.10
tabulate==0.7.7
thrift==0.11.0
unidecode==1.0.22
webencodings==0.5.1
werkzeug==0.14.1
wtforms==2.1
zope.deprecation==4.3.0
```

**Edit**

Here's the actual error message from Cloud Composer:

```
Http error status code: 400 Http error message: BAD REQUEST Additional errors: {"ResourceType":"k448eb7d3c0146d7d-tp/europe-west1-airflow-prod-d08fb03e-gae-typer:appengine.apps.services.versions.create","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Docker image gcr.io/k448eb7d3c0146d7d-tp/1b528566-91c1-496d-ad82-fe0613e3a5e3 was either not found, or is not in Docker V2 format. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui "}
```

Comment: Would be good if the docs can also mention this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation uses [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/). You can check https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds for build logs; look for a build matching your operation UUID.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I tried the link, but it only shows the successful builds.

Comment: It should show every build that the API received, even if it failed, so maybe the builds are not making it to Cloud Build for you.I also recommend installing a minimal set of python packages- installing the amount that you are may override Composer packages