# Granting Cloud Composer permission to check build log for errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-composer

We're deploying Cloud Composer via Terraform and have granted the permissions detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/terraform-create-environments) to the environment service account.

On deployment, we're getting an error that includes a message saying that the service account is missing permissions to view the build logs.

```
Your service account is missing the required permissions to check the build log for errors. You can access them through Cloud Logging, or by running gcloud builds log <log-id> --project <project>.
```

We want Cloud Composer to be able to view the build logs so we tried granting the service account the `roles/cloudbuild.builds.viewer` permission, but we're still getting the same error message.

**What permission is required to grant the Cloud Composer instance permission to view the Cloud Build log?**

I know we can view them manually [as this StackOverflow question details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595315/cloud-composer-build-logs-where-are-they?rq=2), however, we'd like them to be surfaced to Cloud Composer as well as being able to view them in console.

Comment: Hiya, what composer version are you using? Looks like there was a similar post about that issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750097/google-cloud-composer-library-installation-failure

Comment: We managed to get the package installed, had the wrong pinned version. However, it's the build logs we want Composer to be able to see! Will update the question to remove the pypi error as it's not important

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Just to do a quick test, will it be possible that you assigned an overly-excessed role such as Owner or Editor to the SA and check if you can see the Cloud Build logs from Composer? If this turns out to be true then it will be 100% something related with IAM.